# Combining Two Select Queries MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables : `items` and `comments`.

I want to select all items which a user commented on.

For simplicity, lets assume the `items` table has two columns : `item_id` and `item_content`. Let the `comments` table have 3 columns `user_id`, `item_id` and `comment_content`.

I am given the `user_id` of the commenting user, I need to first select all the `item_id` from the `comments` table, where `user_id = myUserId`.

This is a basic query `SELECT item_id FROM comments WHERE user_id = '$myUserId'`.

Then I need to select the `item_content` for each `item_id` returned by the previous query.

I was thinking of doing a `while($row = $my_first_query->fetch_array())` loop, and inside of it doing something like `SELECT item_content FROM item WHERE item_id = $row["item_id"]` 
 however this is a bit messy and I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this, by combining the two queries into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM items t1
INNER JOIN comments t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE t2.user_id = myUserId
```

The approach you suggested of first querying the `comments` table and then looping over the result set is inefficient.  In a join, MySQL can handle this algebra much faster than your PHP code.

Comment: I'm trying to run your code in phpmyAdmin SQL first to test it and I'm getting this weird error : `#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

Comment: This is probably caused by either that `comments` and `items` have different table collations, or the `item_id` fields in these two tables have different collations.

Comment: Do this: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'items'` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'comments'` ... what are the collations of these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what you want to do exactly, you can just use a JOIN clause. The "header" table info will be found within all rows, so it might not be what you want to do.

Another way would be to run two distinct queries, the first one unchanged and the second one with a join. You would then have one result with the header, and the other with all the details that you could go through. It's more performant than run the same query over and over network wise.